# Can´t load font in WordPress site due to CORS policy

Tags: html, wordpress, https, cors

I am unable to load a font file for my WordPress website. This happens specifically in Chrome browsers, Safari and others don't seem to share this issue.

The font files are located on the same folder where the rest of the assets and public files are contained. These load without any problem, images, css, javascript etc. Only font files seem to cause this problem.

The console shows the following error:

Access to font at 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/font-file.otf' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

As stated before, in other browsers, like Safari, the fonts load with no problem. I would like to solve this issue so it works across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check **wordPress address** and **site address** in your blog Settings > General settings. 
Here whole answer: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278512/access-to-font-not-allowed-by-cors-policy